# Unable to Access local Share Windows 7

Tags: windows, network-shares

I am unable to access Network shares, this includes mapping a drive or access via UNC.
To simplify I created  local share on my windows 7 computer
`\\myhostname\share (C:\temp\share)`, given it full folder and share permissions.

> share -everyone read/write, I am owner
>    Folder - everyone full control - I am owner

I can see the share after entering  `\\\myhostname\.`
Share is also seen in windows explorere , Network , machinename...
But after I try to look inside or access the share   (hourglass for  30 seconds) I receive the following message

> "\\myhostname\share is not accessable. You might not have permission
>   to use this network resource..."

Same message mapping netowrk drive

Network and sharing is configured.

Network Discovery on.
Turn on file and print sharing on
tried both 128 and 40 bit etc...

Network Troubleshooter show nothing.

All other network functions are fine. (Internet,SSH,outlook)
reg entry for LSA is restrictanonymous=0
I can ping my host and Windows firewall is disabled (to rule that out).

thanks in advance

Comment: Tried turning off password protected sharing?

Comment: Also have you disabled the firewall?